# How do I receive a signal the question voted for closure is worth close-vote retracting

Tags: support, feature-request

Sometimes I vote for questions closure (usually I do not post an explanation comment why I vote for closure since I consider the reasons I choose perfectly describing the issue I can see with the particular question).

However the question can obviously be corrected so that the issue I could see is completely fixed. The problem is as it seems to me there is no convenient way to know if the question you have voted for closure was edited. There are the question edited popped up on top but there is still too broad scope that includes all the edits.

So my question is either asking for support or feature request (hence tagging with both the tags). If there is a way to watch for questions you have voted to be closed or if no, does it make sence to introduce such the filter/feature?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't particularly worry about it.

If the question has your close vote, but doesn't get closed (presumably because the OP fixed the post and people stopped putting more close votes on it) then you have nothing to worry about. If the post doesn't get closed in 3 days (I think it's 3...) the close votes disappear anyway.

If it does manage to get closed, then when the edits are made, OP or someone else will say "Hey, this is a good post again. Let's re-open it." The Reopen Review Queue goes so quickly, that in the 6 years I've been on this site, I've only managed to get 10, and no single person has managed to get 250 yet. So do not worry, if it's a good post, it will get reopened quickly.

What I will say is that if you feel a question could be salvaged by some edits, perhaps it doesn't need a close vote. The best course of action might be a one line sentence that says "This question could be improved by ..." - especially if you think the asker is likely to edit the post accordingly.

Comment: What is the practical purpose of retracting feature then? If I am getting you right once voted for question closure I should not care of the further state of that question?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying - you should care. But you also shouldn't have to stay up at night waiting for someone to edit their post so you can retract it. There's a couple reasons why you might retract your vote. You see edits that make your close vote not warranted. You see some comments or other explanation and decide the close vote wasn't warranted in the first place. You accidentally cast a close vote and feel you should retract it because it doesn't belong.

Comment: Yes, but to see those edits or comments I need a signal that the issue I voted for has been amended. Otherwise I need to go through all the edited questions to recall if that particular one which I voted against. Because edited questions which one day caught my attention for me personally have bigger weigth than other edited questions.

Comment: If it's more important to you, leave a comment and ask them to respond so when they've updated it. And honestly, if you can't quickly summarize what's wrong with the post (to put in the comment, because why bother commenting without the help!) it's unlikely they're going to be able to salvage it anyway. But honestly, close votes should not be for questions with problems. Close votes should be for questions you do not believe can be salvaged. If you're often finding that people are editing questions to make them good when you've already cast a close vote, you're probably closing too often.

Comment: "But honestly, close votes should not be for questions with problems". This is arguable. However I got your point. Thank you!